# Can I turn a latent variable be treated as an observed variable?

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics, latent-variable

I am a doctoral candidate and for my dissertation research I am using two standardized scales as independent variables.  Because these have not been used with my particular population, I needed to do some validation.  Both produced good alphas, but both failed when it came to the CFA. I've been told that I can just simplify the model and use the global scores, treating them as observed variables. Is this true?  If so, I need to find out more about this and give my major professor some justification for this approach.  Examples where others have done this would be most helpful, too!

Comment: If you were my student, I would be concerned about sweeping the conclusions from the CFA under the rug. You can certainly go ahead and just use the scale scores as observed IVs, but this comes the big assumption that they are measured without error. However, it might be that the "standard" CFA is not the "best" model in your particular situation, but it's impossible to say, given your question as it stands. Can you please edit your question to add more detail about your data (how many items, distributed how), and how you estimated your CFA (software, code, specifications)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any good references for you, but yes, you can do this. The question will be what the results mean and that would depend on the specifics of the tests. If they have good alphas as single tests, that means the averaged correlations among items aren't too bad. That's an aspect of reliability. But what about validity? The fact that the items correlate well does not mean they measure something useful.

For example, suppose I was interested in the math ability of engineering students in a college. Further suppose I made up a test of elementary school arithmetic. If I gave that test to those students, it is likely that the Cronbach alpha would be quite high. But would it be measuring what I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Sum scores are factor scores if you have equal weighted loadings (think of a Rasch model if you are familiar with that). So just using the sum scores because your factor model "failed" (not sure what that means) does not solve the issue. By using sum scores you are actually assuming a very strict parametrization of your CFA.